# How to change the position of HTML elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site in WordPress and a widget generates this login, but I want to change the position of these two elements, it is a pity that I cannot edit the html code and I can only make the change with JavaScript

I'm trying to get the red down and the green up

I deal with CSS, but not responsive, now I am dealing with JavaScript but I am not very skilled with it

[image]

[image]

these are the two elements of the HTML

```
<div class='mo-openid-app-icons'>
<p style='color:#000000; width: fit-content;'> Conectar con Google</p>Login with Google</span></a>
</div> <br><br/>
<a class="lost-pass-link" href="" title="Contraseña perdida">¿Perdiste tu contraseña?</a>                                       
<p class="forgetmenot login-remember">
    <label for="popupRememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" id="popupRememberme"/>
        Recuérdame                                          
    </label>
</p>
<p class="submit login-submit">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit"
    class="button button-primary button-large"
    value="Iniciar sesión"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to"
    value="https://bloque10.unimagdalena.edu.co/ovateca/"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="77ba00d276"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="eduma_login_user">
</p>
```

I really appreciate any help

Comment: You'll need to show a lot more of the HTML. You only have part of the HTML for the content of the green box. Since HTML is text, please add it as formatted text, not an image.

Comment: Please view [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you create a snippet it'll make it easier for others to help.

Comment: Use insertBefore or insertAfter

Comment: @lurker yeah, my site is a wordpress and the code is somewhat dirty, that's why I only put the two elements
I already added formatted text

Comment: My point was that the code you show isn't complete even for just those two elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the element and append it to the form, because `appendChild()`, doesn't create a new element, just take it from its place to the end of parent.

```js
let login = document.querySelector('#loginform');
let google = document.querySelector('.mo-openid-app-icons');
// Move login with google to bottom of the form
login.appendChild(google);
// Do you need to delete those <br>?
let brs = login.querySelectorAll('br');
brs.forEach((br) => { br.remove(); });
```

```html
<form id="loginform">
<div class='mo-openid-app-icons'>
<p style='color:#000000; width: fit-content;'> Conectar con Google</p>Login with Google</span></a>
</div> <br><br/>
<a class="lost-pass-link" href="" title="Contraseña perdida">¿Perdiste tu contraseña?</a>                                       
<p class="forgetmenot login-remember">
    <label for="popupRememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" id="popupRememberme"/>
        Recuérdame                                          
    </label>
</p>
<p class="submit login-submit">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit"
    class="button button-primary button-large"
    value="Iniciar sesión"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to"
    value="https://bloque10.unimagdalena.edu.co/ovateca/"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="77ba00d276"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="eduma_login_user">
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may insert a temporary element before the blue element, then swap the positions of blue and red elements using their common parent's [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) method.

```js
const redDiv = document.querySelector('.red');

const placeholder = document.createElement('span')
const blueP = document.querySelector('.blue');

const parent = redDiv.parentElement;
parent.insertBefore(placeholder, blueP);
parent.insertBefore(blueP, redDiv);
parent.insertBefore(redDiv, placeholder);
parent.removeChild(placeholder);
```

```css
.red { 
  border: 1px dashed red; 
}
.blue {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <div class="red">red</div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class="blue">blue</p>
</form>
```